# tag rename request: compiler -> compiler-construction (major pollution problem)

Tags: feature-request, tags

The [compiler](/questions/tagged/compiler) tag is very badly polluted with questions about specific compilers, contrary to its tag wiki.

There are in fact many more of these than there are relevant questions, by a factor of four or five to one.

It's a poor choice of name. The confusion would be eliminated if the tag was renamed to [compiler-construction](/questions/tagged/compiler-construction).

Comment: compiler-design? compiler-development?

Comment: No. I'm not saying that [compiler] is a useful tag, but I disagree that it be completely replaced with [compiler-construction].

Comment: @Patashu The term used by the practitioners is Compiler Construction. That's what the courses are called for example.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Any reasons for your choice? A reason for continuing the current confusion for example?

Comment: @Patashu Also a 'more formidable' tag name would keep out more incorrect questions.